# Returning table from table-valued function and set that value in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

I have a table valued function. Also I have scalar valued function within I have  declared a temp table. I want to execute the table valued function inside of scalar valued function and set that value in temp table soemething like this

```
 **Exec @tempTable=TableValuedFunction**
```

How could i do this?

Here is the table valued function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Functiont]()
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(   
SELECT d.*, b.Name AS Name, ps.Name AS PaymentSystemName, c.UserName AS UserName, c.FirstName AS ClientFirstName, c.LastName AS LastName, c.Number AS DocumentNumber, c.Id
FROM Document AS d
JOIN System AS ps ON d.SystemId = ps.Id
JOIN Client AS c ON c.Id = d.ClientId
LEFT JOIN Shop AS b ON b.Id = d.ShopId
WHERE d.OperationTypeId IN (2, 4, 5) AND c.Type = 1
)
```

Comment: How does your TVF result looks like?

Comment: Look above i have edited my post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to have a table variable in which the structure is the same (*or depends on your desired columns*) in the result of your TVF . Example:

```
DECLARE @tempTable AS TABLE 
(
   .. columns here ...
)
```

Then insert the rows return from your TVF into the table variable:

```
INSERT INTO @tempTable
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fn_Functiont]()
```

Answer (score 2):

With this approach you need to define the table variable in advance. Table Variables also not very good for performance if the data volume is large.
As per my experience you should use a Temporary table rather than a table Variable. With this approach we can also avoid table creation script.

```
SELECT * INTO #TempVariable FROM [dbo].[fn_Functiont]()
```